# Is is possible to open and close the same cv2 window several times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

My program is about show the image from a Camera with open cv2 on python.

User can open and close the same window (by the window name) several times.

The first time user try to close everything runs ok, but when try to close in the second time, python freezes.

I'm using `cv2.destroyWindow(windowName)`, but I tried `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`, `cv2.waitKey(1)` after destroy before, none of these works.

I'm on Windows OS, I saw this problem is very common on MAC OS

User choices:

```
s1 = View()

while is_true:
    print("1 -> Start Camera")
    print("2 -> Close Camera")
    print("3 -> End")

    usr_input = input()


    if usr_input == "1":
        s1.show("topic1", frame) #frame is the image from camera"  
    elif usr_input == "2":  
        s1.close("topic1")
    elif usr_input == "3":
        is_true = False
    else: 
        print("Invalid month")
```

View class:

```
class View:        
    def show(self, name, frame):
        cv2.imshow(name, frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    def close(self, name):
        cv2.destroyWindow(name)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: Please show a minimal example of your code. Thank you.

Comment: I already updated the question, Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to mix `input() ` and `waitKey()`  - they handle the keyboard in very different ways. Nor am I sure you should use `waitKey()` after closing all windows. `waitKey()` actually uses its slot to redraw the windows.

Comment: To be honest, I just saw that I *have* to use it, and it was working (to show image it was the only way to work as I wanted to)

Comment: better create minimal working example which we could copy and run it .

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message ?

Comment: Terminal, but it doesn't show any error, just freeze and when I force to exit closing the window it just stop running

Comment: More specific, I'm using Windows PowerShell

Comment: I also tried to get the error with try/catch

Comment: it works for me on Linux so it can be bug on Windows . You should rather write to cv2's author for help. It may need changes in C/C++ code which is used by cv2.